# Configure HTTPS trust storefor play framework 2.2.4

Tags: java, https, playframework, keystore, truststore

I have an application in which I call some SOAP web services. When I called these services, I got an invalid certificate error.

---

To resolve this problem, I added the security certificate for the web service in the keystore located at the path `%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts`. 
Now when I call the web services from a standalone application, I get the data successfully.

---

But, when I try to call the same web service from my web application(built using **Play framework 2.2.4**), I get the same error as earlier(i.e. invalid certificate). 
After searching for a solution, I discovered that I should configure the play framework to use that keystore.

I am trying to configure the play framework 2.2.4 to use a custom keystore and I have some doubts.
(I have followed the instructions in the following link [https configuration for play framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ConfiguringHttps), but it doesn't seem to be clear to me)

1. Where should I specify the properties like **https.keystore**, **https.keystorePassword**? I mean, should I put them in the `application.conf` file, or should I put them in the environment variables for the OS, or do I have to specify them while running the application.
2. Also, I have tried to specify these properties while running the application (like `play -Dhttps.port=9443 -Dhttps.keyStore=<Path to the keystore> -Dhttps.keyStorePassword=<Password> run`), but it doesn't work.

As I am new to play framework, it would be really helpful if someone can share the steps or a small tutorial to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there is a difference between keystore and truststore. While the former holds private keys, the latter contains public keys/certificates of other parties. What you referred to in the first paragraph (cacerts) is a truststore.

Therefore, the if you specify `https.keyStore` you're not configuring the store that contains the certificates that you want to accept from other parties.

Use `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` to configure the trust store. More options are described here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29587_01/PlatformServices.60x/ps_security/src/csec_ssl_jsp_start_server.html or in the debugging guide: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. Can you share some information on how to configure the trust store for play framework 2.2.4?

Comment: Have you tried the debugging options? Also, be aware that if you have a password for the trust store, there's another property to set that.

Comment: I realize that I have to set a password property separately, and I did that. My concern is, for play framework, the properties which you mentioned have different names and the ones which you gave don't work. The link which you shared is for Tomcat.(I suppose).

Comment: No. The link you provided (https config) is about whether the play framework serves via https. Therefore you need a keystore and therefore the properties have a prefix named https.*. What you need is the truststore, which defines which certificates are accepted. The links I provided are not about tomcat, but about the JVM. If you enable debugging, you will see which certifcates you get from the server and which your JVM uses to validate them against.

Comment: Ok, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can start the play Netty server in https mode and to use certificates.

In the server can achieve it using -D parameters for Netty.

1) sbt "project pepeGrillo-server" "run -Dhttps.port=9443 -Dhttp.port=disabled -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 
-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true 
-Dplay.server.https.keyStore.path={path-4-server-cer-for-domain}localhost.jks
-Dplay.server.https.keyStore.password={your-password}"
```

2) Then you need to setup the play ws client to use trust store. Add the following to the application.conf. That will ensure that the injected ws has the web-security settings to use your client trusted keys

```
play.ws.ssl {
  keyManager = {
    stores = [
      { type = "JKS", path = "/etc/containerHostca.jks", password = "noSe"}
    ]
  }
  trustManager = {
    stores = [
      { type = "JKS", path = "/etc/containerHosttrust.jks", password = "carloTA" }
    ]
  }
}
```

## Here is how to create the certificates

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CertificateGeneration